# Access JSON chunk exported from Gatsby Static Query

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have a React Component in a Gatsby app that is using the [`useStaticQuery`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/) hook to pull in data from the GraphQL layer. This component gets used in my application, but it also gets used as part of a JavaScript embed/widget that is created in a separate Webpack configuration.

I don't want the widget to depend on Gatsby, so I've shimmed the relevant bits of Gatsby, but I still need to pass in data to the shim I've created for `useStaticQuery`. I found that my Gatsby app is generating a file at `public/static/d/2250905522.json` that contains a perfect representation of the query data, and I'd like to use it like so:

```
// This file gets substituted when importing from `gatsby`

import queryResult from "../public/static/d/2250905522.json"

export const useStaticQuery = () => queryResult.data

export const graphql = () => {}
```

This works, but I haven't figured out where this is coming from or how to determine the file name in a way that is deterministic/stable. How is Gatsby determining this file name, and what internals might I use to do the same?

Edit: I found [this routine](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/610b5812a815f9ecff422e9087c851cd103c8e7e/packages/gatsby/src/utils/websocket-manager.js#L89-L95) in the Gatsby codebase that appears to be using `staticQueryComponent.hash` to determine the number. `staticQueryComponent` is being destructured from `store.getState()` where `store` is associated with Redux, but I'm still not sure where the hash is being determined yet.

Edit 2: Found [another mention of this in the documentation here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/20afc1b7fbd0e7d722f93f7d345531ce48bb5de7/docs/docs/static-vs-normal-queries.md#replacing-queries-with-json-imports). It sounds like `hash` is a hash of the query itself, so this will change over time if the query changes (which is likely), so I'm still looking for the routine used to compute the hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatsby is using [murmurhash](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/610b5812a815f9ecff422e9087c851cd103c8e7e/packages/babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries/src/murmur.js) with a seed of `"abc"` to calculate the hash of the full text of the query (including whitespace). This occurs in [babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/eafb8c6e346188f27cf1687d26544c582ed5952a/packages/babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries/src/index.js#L144).

Since the reused components are isolated from Gatsby, the `graphql` tagged template literal can be shimmed in order to get the original query for hashing:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      gatsby: path.resolve(__dirname, "gatsby-shim.js"),
    },
  },
}
```

```js
// gatsby-shim.js
import { murmurhash } from "babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries/murmur"
import {
  stripIgnoredCharacters,
} from "graphql/utilities/stripIgnoredCharacters"

const GATSBY_HASH_SEED = "abc"

const hashQuery = (query) =>
  murmurhash(
    stripIgnoredCharacters(query),
    GATSBY_HASH_SEED
  ).toString()

export const graphql = query => hashQuery(query.raw[0])
```

This results in the query hash being passed into `useStaticQuery`, which can be shimmed similarly to retrieve the cached query from disk.

Also worth noting, newer versions of Gatsby store the StaticQuery result data in `public/page-data/sq/d/[query hash].json`.

**If you're looking to do something similar**, I've written up a much longer blog post about [the details of this process and the solution I arrived at here](https://coreyward.svbtle.com/exporting-an-embeddable-react-component-from-a-gatsby-app).

Comment: Hi, is there any chance you can share what is in gatsby-shim.js? I am needing to do something very similar to what you have described to export a Nav component into a legacy site. I hope you don't mind but I am going to peek at your profile and ask you over email too.

Answer (score 2):

Due to changes in the babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries, coreyward's (awesome) answer should be updated to:

```
const { stripIgnoredCharacters } = require('graphql/utilities/stripIgnoredCharacters');
const murmurModule = require('babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries/murmur');
const murmurhash = typeof murmurModule === 'function' ? murmurModule : murmurModule.murmurhash;

const GATSBY_HASH_SEED = 'abc';

function hashQuery(query) {
  const result = murmurhash(stripIgnoredCharacters(query), GATSBY_HASH_SEED).toString();
  return result;
}

module.exports = hashQuery;
```

The changes are:

- fix the way murmurhash is imported. Credit to github user veloce, see: https://github.com/birkir/gatsby-source-graphql-universal/pull/16/files
- Change to using `stripIgnoredCharacters` in order to match the updated way that gatsby internally hashes queries by first stripping whitespace and comment lines for efficiency.